# Sql server DELETE and WITH clause

Tags: sql-server

I need to build an SQL statement to delete from certain table the records that match another select statement.

In Teradata we use

```
delete from table1 
where (col1, col2) in (
  select col1,col2
  from table2
)
```

While in SQL Server it's not allowed to have more than 1 column in the WHERE..IN clause. I thought I can use the WITH clause:

```
with tempTable(col1,col2) as (
select col1,col2
from table2
)
delete from table1
where table1.col1 = tempTable.col1
and table1.col2 = tempTable.col2
```

How to use WITH..DELETE clause? Is there another way?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should do it:

```
DELETE Table1
 from Table1 t1
  inner join tempTable t2
   on t2.Col1 = t1.Col1
    and t2.Col2 = t1.Col2
```

Comment: ...you could use the WITH clause, but this way is simpler.

Comment: Thinking about it, I see no reason to use the WITH clause. I use WITH when things get seriously messy or complex, and deleting from a table based on a simple join to another table isn't complex enough to warrant the extra coding effort.

Comment: I agree that creating a CTE (WITH) isn't really warranted, but as to how--it's right there. The join in the answer is to the CTE (note the name...).

Comment: If you wanted to use a CTE (WITH), then you need to specify from which table you want to delete.

In the example that you gave above, you would need the following query (note the "delete t1" instead of "delete from"):

with tempTable(col1, col2) as (
    select col1, col2
    from table2
)
delete t1
from table1 t1
where t1.col1 = tempTable.col1
and t1.col2 = tempTable.col2

Answer (score 5):

First build a query that selects the rows you need:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM [Table1] t1
INNER JOIN [Table2] t2 ON t1.[col1] = t2.[col1] AND t1.[Col2]=t2.[Col2]
```

*Test it* to make sure it returns exactly the rows you want to delete.  Then turn it into a delete statement by changing the "SELECT" to "DELETE" and removing the column list:

```
DELETE t1
FROM [Table1] t1
INNER JOIN [Table2] t2 ON t1.[col1] = t2.[col1] AND t1.[Col
```

Answer (score 2):

```
delete from table1 t1 where exists 
  ( 

   select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 > t2.col2

)
```

Comment: The syntax is incorrect, but the general idea is correct. SQL Server can optimize this so it should perform as well as a solution using a join while being easier to read IMO.

Answer (score 1):

```
with tempTable(col1,col2) as (
  select col1,col2
  from table2
)
delete table1 from tempTable
where table1.col1 = tempTable.col1
and table1.col2 = tempTable.col2
```

Comment: It's always better to include some explanation rather than just having a code-only answer as that makes it more useful to future readers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT TOP 50000 *
from v020101hist  order by data
)
DELETE FROM CTE
```